# How to include jasmine js in development project

Tags: javascript, jasmine

What is the preferred method of including jasmine in a project in development environments only?

Im new to it, but from what i can see it has to be downloaded and the added to project manually?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

You can set flag in your application config file based on your development version or production version.

Using the flag you can add the condition  to execute your Jasmine.js test suites.

Answer (score 0):

I use package.json file.. Ad Jasmine how devDependencies..
https://github.com/gianarb/ng-analytics.js/blob/master/package.json#L7

Now you can use npm install for download dependencies.. and npm install --production doesn't install devDeps..